# knockout How to change the model binded to elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm really just starting into knockout and so far it is pretty impressive.  With that, there is also an issue I am running into.

I'm trying to take a list of binded objects and when on is clicked, I want it take that model and bind it to another view for further editing, no issues there. The problem I run into is that I get an error saying I *cannot bind multiple times to the same element*.  I have read the `ko.cleanNode([domElement])` can be used to circumvent it, but that is really meant to be used internally.  I have done some searching and people mention you should use `with` but I don't think that applies to what I want to do.

Is there a way to apply the bindings but then just update the underlying model context?

Simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kw5sj/1/) example.  My js code starts on like 119, above it the ko mapping plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use the external resources to add external resources to your fiddle rather than pasting them into your fiddle.

Second, on your problem, the easiest way to do something like this is to have a `SelectedItem` property in your view model and bind the child view to it. Something like this:

```
var MyViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.MyItems = ko.observableArray();
    self.SelectedItem = ko.observable();
}

var MyChildViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.SomeProperty = ko.observable();
}
```

Now populate `MyItems` with instances of `MyChildViewModel` and set `SelectedItem` to whichever item in `MyItems` you want to have as your child and bind the child view to `SelectedItem`:

```
<div id="theChildView" data-bind="with: SelectedItem">
    <span data-bind="text: SomeProperty"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't find a CDN of the KO mapping plugin, that is why it is in the fiddle.

Comment: @Justin: why not use https://raw.github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.js

Comment: Tried but jsFiddle didn't like it.  jsFiddle even makes mention that adding an external resource from github like that may cause unexpected effects.